# Can I use bubble wrap / pluriball to insulate my shed or it is just a waste of time?

Tags: walls, insulation, shed

I would like to make my small shed / laboratory a little less cold / humid during winter.

The main points I can "attack" are the very thin windows and some holes between the wall and roof, here's a picure of the problem:
[image: Problem]

And here's a potential fix obtained rolling bubble wrap / pluriball and pushing it in the gap so that it is quite a tight fit:
[image]

Am I just wasting time?
Is there a better option without making too much mess?
I am a bit scared about using special products because if the fix doesn't go well (maybe I get mould or other issues) the products can be hard to remove.

Thanks for your time and kind help.

Comment: I didn't know until I searched the term that "pluriball" is more commonly known as bubble packaging, also known as Bubble Wrap™

Comment: What other "special products" have you considered? There are many products _specifically designed_ to insulate, and quite a number of them are designed to fill small gaps like the one you've shown. Maybe detail a few things you've considered, and what your concerns are about them. I mean, I could see getting mold growing if you're thinking about stuffing some bread in the cracks...

Comment: Hi @FreeMan!
I don't have much knowledge, this is why I came asking but I know there are spray products that produce a foam that hardens but I didn't try anything specific.